# AnchorPane responsivo javaFX

Tags: javafx, responsive

Tengo un problema a la hora de de hacer que un anchorpane cambie de contenido.
Si hago la pantalla grande el anchorpane se agranda como esperaría, pero el contenido que le inserté se queda estatico, espero me puedan ayudar.

PD: El fondo verde es el backgroundcolor del mismo anchorpane con id rootAnchorPane.

PD2: En teoria, tanto la ventana principal, como la que meto al anchorpane son responsivas por que si abro en sceneBuilder el fxml que meto al rootAnchorPane este si se hace grande con normalidad, pero ya cuando lo corro en Netbeans y meto el fxml al anchorPane se queda como en la foto

[image: Demostración de como se ve el contenido corriendo en Netbeans]

Codigo que uso para insertar el contenido en el anchor pane

```
@FXML
    public void cargarMenuClientes(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/edu/softech/"
                + "InterfazJavaFX/gui/fxml/cliente/window_clientes.fxml"));

        rootAnchorPane.getChildren().addAll(pane);
    }
```

Comment: No te recomiendo que uses anchorPane, yo solo utilizo Borders, vbox y hbox, en ocasiones stacks.

Answer (score 0):

AnchorPane es un modo de diseño fijo, por lo tanto no se ajusta según se acomode sino como se diseña. Si quieres hacerlo responsivo, te recomiendo hacer uso de BorderPane, así aunque sea grande o chico, se amoldara de manera mas sencilla sin que tengas problemas.

Answer (score 0):

**Los AnchorPane son adaptables anclando sus lados**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo hay tres Anchorpane: uno amarillo , uno verde y el otro rojo .
El amarillo nunca se ve porque es padre de los otros y sus hijos se adaptan porque sus lados están anclados al padre  .Al anchorpane verde no se le puede dar un valor fijo para anclarlo a la derecha porque ese valor puede llegar a ser menor que el declarado . Con el verde no hay problema porque los valores horizontales se incrementan de izquierda a derecha.
por ejemplo `AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(left, 0.0);` quiere que decir que Anchorpane  left se anclará  a 0 pixeles del fondo de Anchorpane root . Aunque root se aumente verticalmente , left siempre estará a 0 pixeles de el fondo de root . así con todos los lados .
Los métodos `setBottomAnchor()` ,`setTopAnchor` ,`setLeftAnchor`y`setRightAnchor()`  son métodos estáticos y no están en los nodos hijos que pueden ser de cualquier otro nodo , sino en `Anchorpane` . Básicamente se declara cómo un nodo children de un Anchorpane debe estar anclado al mismo  basado en cuán cerca debe estar a uno(s) de su(s)  lado(s) aunque los valores cambien en tiempo de ejecución,  el padre readapta a sus hijos de acuerdo a sus anclajes . [Clase AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)

**este es un ejemplo de una app funcional de javafx en una sola clase**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
        root.setPrefSize(200, 200);

        AnchorPane left = new AnchorPane();
        left.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(left, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(left, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(left, AnchorPane.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(left, 0.0);

        AnchorPane right = new AnchorPane();
        right.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(right, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(right, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(right, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(right, 100.0);

        root.getChildren().addAll(left, right);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```